# STM32 HAL I2C is returning OVR (overrun/under-run) error when using an interrupt driven approach

Tags: c, interrupt, stm32, i2c, overrun

I am attempting to implement an interrupt driven I2C slave that is continuously ready to receive (except when transmitting) on the STM32L051. The problem is that I keep receiving the HAL_I2C_ERROR_OVR error in the HAL_I2C_ErrorCallback. The below code is just an example and is configured to receive a 3 byte message and respond with a single byte status. Running this code triggers the OVR error once the master transmits and then appears to continuously trigger the I2C1_IRQHandler, tying up other operations. The slave cannot use stretching so I have disabled it as shown in the below code. I am fairly new to HAL and have mostly been using the STM32Fxx series with the std peripheral libraries. I have reviewed the published examples, even copied some into my more complex code-base, only to get the same OVR error. Do any of you guys have any suggestions/advice/etc. that could push me towards a workable solution?

System Clock Speed: 16MHz

I2C Bus Speed: 10KHz

Thanks.

```
//**** Slave Rx/Tx ****//
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
    int responseSize = 1;
    int bytesToReceive = 3; 
    bool error = false; 
  /* USER CODE END 1 */
  /* MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------*/
  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */

  HAL_Init();

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();


  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();

  /* Initialize interrupts */
  MX_NVIC_Init();

  i2c_response[0] = 0x01;
  responseSize = 1;

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
        //**** Slave Rx/Tx Interrupt based ****//
        if(slaveRxCallbackTriggered)
        {   
            slaveRxCallbackTriggered = false;

            if(responseSize > 0)
            {
                if(!IOModule_TransmitToMaster(i2c_response,responseSize))
                {
                    error = true;
                }
            }           

            IOModule_ReceiveFromMaster(bytesToReceive); 
        }
        else
            IOModule_ReceiveFromMaster(bytesToReceive);

  /* USER CODE END WHILE */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    I2C Receive data from master
 *------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
bool IOModule_ReceiveFromMaster(int numberOfBytes)
{
    bool result = false;

    if(HAL_I2C_GetState(&hi2c1) == HAL_I2C_STATE_READY)
    {       
        HAL_StatusTypeDef status = HAL_I2C_Slave_Receive_IT(&hi2c1, (uint8_t *)i2c_rx_array, numberOfBytes);

        if(status == HAL_OK)
        {
            result = true;
        }
    }


    return result;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    I2C Transmit data to master
 *------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
bool IOModule_TransmitToMaster(uint8_t txBuffer[], int bufferSize)
{
    bool result = false;    

    while (HAL_I2C_GetState(&hi2c1) != HAL_I2C_STATE_READY)
  {
  } 

    HAL_StatusTypeDef status = HAL_I2C_Slave_Transmit(&hi2c1, (uint8_t*)txBuffer, bufferSize, 10000);

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC,GPIO_PIN_11,GPIO_PIN_RESET);

    if(status == HAL_OK)
    {   
        result = true;
    }

    return result;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    I2C Slave Rx Complete Callback
 *------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void HAL_I2C_SlaveRxCpltCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef *I2CxHandle)
{   
    slaveRxCallbackTriggered = true;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    I2C Error Callback
 *------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void HAL_I2C_ErrorCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c)
{
    lastErrorCode = HAL_I2C_GetError(&hi2c1);
}

//I2C1 init
void MX_I2C1_Init(void)
{
  hi2c1.Instance = I2C1;
  hi2c1.Init.Timing = 0x000006C5;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0x24;
  hi2c1.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
  hi2c1.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2Masks = I2C_OA2_NOMASK;
  hi2c1.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_ENABLE;
  HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1);

    /**Configure Analogue filter 
    */
  HAL_I2CEx_ConfigAnalogFilter(&hi2c1, I2C_ANALOGFILTER_ENABLE);
}


void HAL_I2C_MspInit(I2C_HandleTypeDef* hi2c)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
  if(hi2c->Instance==I2C1)
  {  
    /**I2C1 GPIO Configuration    
    PB6     ------> I2C1_SCL
    PB7     ------> I2C1_SDA 
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_OD;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF1_I2C1;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* Peripheral clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_I2C1_CLK_ENABLE();
  }
}
```

Master Tx/Rx

```
int main(void)
{
    //**** Master Tx/Rx ****//
    ioModule_response[0] = 0xA0;
    ioModule_response[1] = 0x01;
    ioModule_response[2] = 0xE3;

    while(1)
    {
        if(HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, (uint16_t)0x24, (uint8_t*)ioModule_response, 3, 10000)== HAL_OK)
        {
            if(HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, (uint16_t)0x24, (uint8_t *)i2c_rx_array, 1, 10000) != HAL_OK)
            {
                            //Blink LED and Pause
                LED_Show_StatusCode(2,false);
                HAL_Delay(500);
            }
            else if(i2c_rx_array[0] != 1)
            {
                            //Blink LED and Pause
                LED_Show_StatusCode(3,false);
                HAL_Delay(500);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the STM32Cube MX generated IRQ Handler.

```
void I2C1_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_IRQn 0 */
  if (hi2c1.Instance->ISR & (I2C_FLAG_BERR | I2C_FLAG_ARLO | I2C_FLAG_OVR)) {
    HAL_I2C_ER_IRQHandler(&hi2c1);
  } else {
    HAL_I2C_EV_IRQHandler(&hi2c1);
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_IRQn 1 */
}
```

UPDATE: I am currently exploring the LL API as this seems more like the Standard Peripheral Libraries that I have used in the past.

Comment: **(1)** HAL implement a lot of checks, so it's IRQ_Handlers too slow. Have you seen `I2C_Slave_ISR_IT` handler code? **(2)** If you have oscilloscope - you can toggle test pin in real IRQ handler that placed in `stm32f4xx_it.c` file for view it with I2C SCL,SDA pins. **(3)** If you use HAL just for portability try [LL API](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/sales_and_marketing/presentation/product_presentation/37/55/ff/bc/a8/71/4f/c5/stm32_embedded_software_offering.pdf/files/stm32_embedded_software_offering.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.stm32_embedded_software_offering.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the response. (1) I have reviewed the ISR that is implemented in HAL. The I2C_SlaveReceive_ISR seems pretty simple by itself, but the entire interrupt handler code does jump from the I2C1_IRQHandler to the HAL_I2C_EV_IRQHandler and then finally to the I2C_SlaveReceive_ISR, so I agree it seems a bit overly complex as a whole. (2) I will attempt the scope capture with a debug pin set during the IRQ handler and let you know what I find. (3) I'll give that a look.

Comment: Is the  I2C_IT_EVT  flag cleared in the actual ISR handler? Could you please post the IRQ handler?

Comment: @KooroshHajiani actual handler is default HAL handler. HAL is free for download - so whats new you will see when op will post it?

Answer (score 3):

The solution for me was to ditch HAL completely and go with the LL API as suggested by imbearr. As stated I have used the STM32 standard peripheral libraries in the past and LL is very similar in many ways.

Thanks imbearr for the help.